# Deriving a generating function from a pdf

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, generating-functions

i am trying to derive a generating function from a probability density function (PDF) on $x \geq 0$.

i think i'm supposed to apply the following formula to do this, where $f(x)$ is the PDF.

$\int_{0}^\infty e^{tx} \cdot f(x)dx$

the formula for my specific PDF is below.

$f(x) = \frac{e^{-x/3}}{3}$

so applying the formula from the beginning:

$\int_{0}^\infty e^{tx} \cdot \frac{e^{-x/3}}{3}dx$

i know that the answer is $\frac{1}{1-3t}$, but i am having a lot of trouble with the integration process. i have tried u substitution and integration by parts, but i just can't seem to crack it.

any advice for how to proceed? thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $e^{tx}\cdot e^{-x/3}=e^{x(t-1/3)}$.

Hence, $\int_{0}^\infty e^{tx} \cdot \frac{e^{-x/3}}{3}dx=\frac 13\int_{0}^\infty e^{x(t-1/3)}dx$. Now use $u$ substitution with $u=x(t-1/3)$. Treat $t$ as just a number.

Of course, you need $t<1/3$ for the integral to converge.

Comment: thank you. now i'm stuck on what to do at the end though. i have e^u / (3t - 1), but when i substitute u = x(t - 1/3) again, i don't see how this can make the exponential term drop to 1. is this where the t < 1/3 assumption comes in? if so then i can see how that would work.